# How to plot a secondary axis in facets with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

for these dataframes

```
dd=structure(list(req = c(0, 6.24296787098387e-05, 0.000124859357419677, 
                      0.000187289036129516, 0.000249718714839355, 0.000312148393549194
), st = c(4.20392459337459, 3.101869731322, 3.05827365904846, 
      2.55875394873998, 1.61722938145694, 0.969328686413803), tt = c(1.66320917439717, 
                                                                     1.46619835076717, 
1.47423709334019, 1.39210979230404, 1.24099973128753, 
                                                                     1.15120693233888), nn = 
c(2.09771326762665, 1.74025312387583, 
                                                                                               
 1.74965887129391, 1.64515722021115, 1.38734468460281, 1.30261082263608
                                                                     )), row.names = c(NA, 
  6L), class = "data.frame")

 df=dd
df$sou="A"
df$req=df$req+0.05
dd$sou="B"
out=rbind(df,dd)
```

I want to plot with second axis.

to plot the second axis

```
 fs <- pretty(dd[["req"]])
 pers <- round(1 / fs, 2)
```

then I do:

```
 ggplot(data =out, aes(x=req))  + 
 geom_line(aes(y=st , color = "SS"), size = .8) +
 scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., labels = pers, breaks = fs))+ facet_wrap(~sou, scales = "free")
```

You see that fs and pers are only adapted to B and thus the second axis does not appear.  How to creat fs and pers for each group in out (sou)  and plot them s second axis?

Comment: If you want different panel settings for two facets, I think easiest to make two plots and combine with `patchwork`.

Comment: I have 10 groups in my real data so it will be difuclt to do this 10 time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something with `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` would make sense here. To make this more manageable for 10 facets (but still a little clunky, unfortunately), I pre-process the breaks per facet into a list. Then we just need to specify which element of the list each facet should use for its labels:

```
library(dplyr)
combo <- out |>
  reframe(fs = pretty(req), 
          pers = round(1/fs, 2), .by = sou) |>
  group_split(sou)

make_scale <- function(i) {
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(
    ~., labels = combo[[i]]$pers, breaks = combo[[i]]$fs,
    name = "Axis label on top"))
}

ggplot(data =out, aes(x=req))  + 
  geom_line(aes(y=st , color = "SS"), size = .8) +
  facet_wrap(~sou, scales = "free_x") +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(x = lapply(1:length(combo), 
                             make_scale))
```

[image]

Comment: Thnaks, so for my 10 groups i need to repeat      scale_x_continuous(
      sec.axis = sec_axis(~., labels = combo[[2]]$pers, breaks = combo[[2]]$fs))
      10times?

Comment: Yeah that's annoying. I've updated it to make it instead a function that is applied to each of the facets automatically. Can you check if that works?

Comment: Thanks, that work fine. Can we put lab on that axis? on top